# Corrupted conda cannot to channel

Tags: anaconda, conda

My conda has been corrupted by some reasons....
When I try to update conda or to install a package this, 
I have this message :

```
conda update conda
Error: HTTPError: 403 Forbidden http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
```

My config of conda  is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>conda info
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.2.0a1
       python version : 2.7.12.final.0
     root environment : G:\_dev\anaconda27  (writable)
  default environment : G:\_dev\anaconda27
     envs directories : G:\_dev\anaconda27\envs
        package cache : G:\_dev\anaconda27\pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False


C:\Windows\system32>conda info -a
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 3.2.0a1
       python version : 2.7.12.final.0
     root environment : G:\_dev\anaconda27  (writable)
  default environment : G:\_dev\anaconda27
     envs directories : G:\_dev\anaconda27\envs
        package cache : G:\_dev\anaconda27\pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
root                  *  G:\_dev\anaconda27

sys.version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (defaul...
sys.prefix: G:\_dev\anaconda27
sys.executable: G:\_dev\anaconda27\python.exe
conda location: G:\_dev\anaconda27\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-build.exe
conda-convert: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-convert.exe
conda-develop: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-develop.exe
conda-index: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-index.exe
conda-inspect: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-inspect.exe
conda-metapackage: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-metapackage.exe
conda-render: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-render.exe
conda-server: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-server.exe
conda-sign: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-sign.exe
conda-skeleton: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts\conda-skeleton.exe

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
PATH: G:\_dev\anaconda27\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Shield;G:\_dev\anaconda27;G:\_dev\anaconda27\Scripts;G:\_dev\anaconda27\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;G:\app\emeditor;G:\_dev\googlesdk\google-cloud-sdk\bin
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

License directories:
    C:\Users\aa\.continuum
    C:\Users\aa\AppData\Roaming\Continuum
    G:\_dev\anaconda27\licenses
License files (license*.txt):
Package/feature end dates:
```

How to repair a corrupted conda ?
Can I modify some files manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Miniconda from https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-3.19.0-Windows-x86_64.exe.

Then you should be able to run `conda update conda` again.